# Click and Mousedown Jquery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery 1.9.1 and I have a parent element with two child elements. When I add a handler to the parent element using `mousedown()` and a handlers to the children using `click()` only the parent fires. When I add handlers for all three using `mousedown()` they all fire like I expect them to.

What about the first case prevents a `click` event from being dispatched.

here is a vanilla javascript example of it not working

http://jsfiddle.net/Nxn56/8/

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: The event handlers should all fire, so you probably did something wrong, but without any code this is impossible to answer.

Comment: what about `stopPropagation()`

Comment: stopPropagation would make the parent not trigger, not the other way around.

Comment: Post. Your. Code. Here. Please.

Comment: hmmmm a clear question and a demonstrative example yields one non-answer, a downvote, and 3 votes to close. When did people in this community stop reading. I'll retract and save you all the trouble of ... you know participation.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$(#parent).on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Mouse Down on Parent");
});
$(#child).on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Click On Child");
});
```

Comment: I want both the parent and child element to process the event, but I am more curious about why the click is dispatched under certain circumstances

Comment: It's about the order of the elements, if the child catches an event it will be propagated to the parent, if is the parent catching him, it is not propagated to the childs.